# How would I marshal/ unmarshal a List of java objects to an XML without a root element?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb, xmlmapper

I have a List of java objects with structure as follows

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee 
{
  private Integer id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double income;
   
  //Getters and Setters
}
```

I want to convert it to an XML file whose contents would just be the list without any root element.

Expected Output:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<employee>
    <id>l</id>
    <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
    <income>100. 0</income>
</employee>
<employee>
    <id>2</id>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Mclane</lastName>
    <income>200. 0</income>
</employee>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Jaxb classes or any other java to xml libraries ?
Also is there a way to unmarshall the same back to java POJO?

I tried to marshall a list as is but it just gave out an

If I tried to create a wrapper class and then marshall it, it would just add the wrapper

Code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "employees")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees 
{
  @XmlElement(name = "employee")
  private List<Employee> employees = null;
}
```

Output:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <id>l </id>
        <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
        <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
        <income>100. 0</income>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <id>2</id>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Mclane</lastName>
        <income>200. 0</income>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Comment: That's not a valid XML. A valid XML requires a root element. Probably no XML library will read or write something like it.

Comment: @aled : It is valid.  It may not be well formed, but still would meet XML Specficiation

Comment: Valid includes well-formed, and both require a root. It is in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/.

Comment: Let's be a bit more precise. It is a well-formed external parsed entity (often referred to as a fragment). It is not a well-formed XML document. It is not valid, because validity requires a DTD.

Comment: @aled: See my use case is a bit different. I have to process large chunks of json lists into separate xml files like you see above, these files should just contain the list of individual XML elements. I then lift and shift these xml files to create a final xml file with all the relevant tags. So it doesnt matter if it "valid" xml or not.

Comment: I understand it is not relevant to your use case, but it is relevant to XML libraries that follow the standard, which is probably nearly 100% of them. You probably need to treat each individual XML as a string and concatenate them together.

Answer (score 0):

Although JAXB requires a top level XML element, it does not require the immediate, physical container to be a file. The message can be unmarshaled as an input stream from anywhere. We can use this observation to *contain* each XML message in its own `Base64` stream which can then be stored as a *list of streams* (line-by-line) in one *meta-container* file.

This example reads each line of an input file as a `Base64` encoded stream. Each encoded line contains one `Employee` XML element; thus, each line can be unmarshaled and put into a list of `Employee` objects. Also, the object list can be marshaled, encoded and stored as a single file.

##### Execution

This is a stand-alone Maven project ([zip](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/releases/download/2.1.1/hisrc-higherjaxb-sample-employees-2.1.1-mvn-src.zip)). You can run the test using:

```
mvn -Ptest clean test
```

The [output](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/OUTPUT.txt) shows the test results.

This Maven project includes:

- An XML Schema file [employee.xsd](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/main/resources/employee.xsd) for the `Employee` model
- A JAXB *binding* file [employee.xjb](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/main/resources/employee.xjb) for customizations
- A JUnit test class [EmployeeTest](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/java/org/example/employee/EmployeeTest.java) to demonstrate (un)marshalling
- Sample XML files with `Employee` [data](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/samples).
- The Maven [POM](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/project-pom.xml) file with `hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin`

```
Employees
    src
        main
            java
            resources
                employee.xjb
                employee.xsd
        test
            java
                org/example/employee/EmployeeTest.java
            resources
                simplelogger.properties
            samples
                Employee1.xml
                Employee2.xml
                Employees.b64
    pom.xml
```

The JAXB classes are generated by this plugin in this project's [pom.xml](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/project-pom.xml)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.patrodyne.jvnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hisrc-higherjaxb-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and are generated to:

```
target/generated-sources/xjc/
    org.example.employee
        Employee.java
        ObjectFactory.java
```

##### Testing

The JUnit test class, [EmployeeTest](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/java/org/example/employee/EmployeeTest.java), scans for the sample files and invokes the method `checkSample(File sample)` to provide each file to the tester. For this project, a `JAXBContext` is created and each file in the [samples](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/samples) path is *unmarshaled* to an `employee` object. When successful, the `employee` object is *marshaled* for logging and your review.

In particular, the data file [Employees.b64](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/samples/Employees.b64) demonstrates how a list of XML streams can be stored in one file. The sample file contains two Base64 encoded streams, each on its own line; but, there can be any number of such lines, each representing an XML stream that JAXB can unmarshal.

This code fragment from [`EmployeeTest`](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/blob/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/java/org/example/employee/EmployeeTest.java) shows how a data source file can be read line-by-line to decode and unmarshal the `Employee` data. Then, in reverse, each `Employee` object is marshaled and encoded before writing the list to a target file.

**EmployeeTest#testEmployees()**

```
...
// Read Source
try ( FileReader fr = new FileReader(employeesB64Source) )
{
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
    String employeeB64 = null;
    while ( (employeeB64 = lnr.readLine()) != null )
    {
        String employeeXml = new String(decoder.decode(employeeB64), UTF_8);
        Object root = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(employeeXml));
        if ( root instanceof Employee )
            employeeList.add((Employee) root);
    }
}
...
...
// Write Target
try ( FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(employeesB64Target) )
{
    for ( Employee employee : employeeList )
    {
        String employeeXml = null;
        employeeXml = marshalToString(employee, marshaller);
        String employeeB64 = encoder.encodeToString(employeeXml.getBytes(UTF_8));
        fw.write(employeeB64 + nl);
    }
}
```

##### Bash Bonus

As a bonus, the Linux Bash [`base64`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) command can be used to quickly decode *all* lines in the [b64](https://github.com/patrodyne/hisrc-higherjaxb/tree/master/assembly/samples/employees/src/test/samples/Employees.b64) file:

**Bash Shell**

```
$ base64 --decode Employees.b64

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <firstName>Lokesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Gupta</lastName>
    <income>100.0</income>
</employee>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <id>2</id>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Mclane</lastName>
    <income>200.0</income>
</employee>
```